# Calculate mean or median based on criteria - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for Excel syntax which will do the following:

If the difference between variable 1 and 2 is less than 0.4 then calculate the mean of the two variables. IF the difference between variable 1 and 2 is greater than 0.4, calculate the median value of variables 1,2, and 3.

Many thanks.

Comment: a very simple question, but a valid one nevertheless.  Upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(ABS(A1-A2)<.4,AVERAGE(A1,A2),MEDIAN(A1,A2,A3))
```

Comment: Thank you Scott, very helpful. I'm actually using this to import into a clinical trials database builder. This software apparently also requires an ISBLANK statement before telling it what to do. Is it possible to incorporate this into the above?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, or where it would go.  Try figuring it out on your own, If you get stuck ask a new question with your attempts and some test data and expected output.